# Python: Extract text from website that is not in the raw HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a situation where I am scraping data from webpages and need to store that data (a bunch of strings) in a txt file. I already have the code written to do this for many websites, however I have a roadblock where BeautifulSoup does not seem to work.

Take this website for example: http://www.vucommodores.com/gametracker/launch/gt_mbasebl.html?event=1530990&school=vand&sport=mbasebl&camefrom=&startschool=&

I want to be able to click on the play-by-play button and then extract the text from the 1st inning, 2nd inning, etc. Is anyone aware of a method to do so, because the text is not available in the raw HTML as has been the case with all of my other examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is what BeautifulSoup is meant for. You can use [Selenium for Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) to interact with the page as if from a browser, and simulate the click. Then extract from the html.

Comment: Are you confident this would allow me to extract the text, even though it is not available in the HTML for this particular site (as is)?

Comment: Yes. Once you click on the link, the HTML will be available. Clicking on "play by play" calls some javascript that populates the '.tab-content' div You can verify this by clicking 'play by play', and then right-clicking an element in the table and going to "Inspect Element".

Answer (score 2):

@Lgiro is right. Is you want to manipulate with page elements, for example switch tabs or click buttons, you need simulate a browser and inject javascript into the window. The best tool for this is Selenium. Here are [python-selenium docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io).

Comment: Ok, that seems straight forward enough. But, my other question is whether I would be able to extract the text in that table even though it is not available in the HTML for the main site?

Comment: @RickAhlf, I'm not sure what is unavailable. As I checked, everything is rendered into html. The only problem is that you need to click some buttons in order to get where you want

Comment: I'll work through it and see if I run into any issues. Thanks!